# Adding theorem (numbered by section)

Tags: numbering, lyx

I am trying to add *Theorem (Numbered by Section)* in lyx but the Add icon cannot be selected. Is there a package that I need to download in-order to use this please?

This is the path I am using to add the *Theorem (Numbered by Section)*:

Document>Settings>Modules>Theorem(Numbered by section)

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the module says "Modules required: Theorems or Theorems (AMS)":
[image]

That means that you need to add either of those modules and then you will be able to add this the module "Theorem (Numbered by Section)".